# Get variable from the button's value

Tags: javascript

Can I make a variable on this way, but in console is undefined :(

```
if(document.getElementById("firstBtnn").clicked == true){
    x = document.getElementById("firstBtnn").value;
    console.log(x);
}
else if (document.getElementById("secondBtnn").clicked == true) {
        x = document.getElementById("secondBtnn").value;
        console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as a `clicked` property, as far as I know.

Comment: If you're new to this, consider using jQuery... It'll help you save a lot of time..

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your button element, and then you can assign an event listener, try this:

```js
let button = document.getElementById('btn');

button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.value)
})
```

```html
<button id ="btn" value="VALUE">Click me!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an event listener to listen for the click on the button, once clicked, check the event obj using a conditional and then define your variable.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById("firstBtnn")
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  if (event) {
    x = btn.value;
    console.log(x);
  }
})
```

```html
<button id="firstBtnn" value="some value">click me</button>
```

You can also, run a querySelectorAll on all your button elements and loop them using the event.target to get the one being clicked...

The cleaner way would be to remove the conditional and variable from the mix all together.

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll("button");
btn.forEach((button) => {
  button.addEventListener('click', (event) => console.log(event.target.value))    
})
```

```html
<button id="firstBtnn" value="some value">click me</button>
<br>
<button id="firstBtnn" value="some other value">click me too</button>
```